# How to input the password while executing cmd through java

Tags: java, cmd, runas

I want to write a java program to retrieve the status of all the services running on different servers (approx 20). For this i am using SC command, i am able to do so using the java program. But now i am stuck in a situation where i want to run the SC command as a different user by using RUNAS, the problem that i am facing is that i am not able to input the password once the command has been executed for the first time. Following is the code that i am using :-

```
        String[] command = new String[3];
        command[0] = "cmd";
        command[1] = "/c";
        command[2] = "runas /noprofile /user:domain\\admin \"sc \\\\serverName queryex type= service state= all\"";

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(p.getOutputStream())), true);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {

            new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(),true).println("AdminPassword");

            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        String Input;
        while ((Input = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(Input);
        }            

        String Error;
        while ((Error = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(Error);
        }
```

But i am not been able to print the states of all the services. I am not not sure after providing the password whether i need to capture some other stream or else??

Any help on this?

Thanks

Comment: A security issue might affect you with probably most of the answers here: if you provide the credentials via command-line, they might be available as plain-text when viewing process-lists with task-manager or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In your `while (line != null)` loop you open a new PrintWriter for each line you read. You print the admin password to these writers, but never close or flush them.

Try the `PrintWriter writer` you created above, and `flush()` it after writing the password, otherwise it will still be in the buffer.

You also create several `BufferedReader` on the inputStream of the Process, which might interfere with each other.

So: create only one reader resp. writer for the inputStream, errorStream and outputStream of the Process.

Comment: Hi Thomos, thanks for the reply, i have taken the printwriter code outside the loop (before) and did the flush and close, but still the same result.